# Android SAF Call-Back Missing

Tags: python, android, kivy

Running a Python Kivy App on Android 13 with API 33, using Android's Storage Area Framework (as there's little choice on modern Android), and although this minimum app compiles fine with Buildozer, its not running the on_activity_result function once a directory has been selected. Is there a problem with the listener configuration?

```
from jnius import autoclass
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.clock import mainthread

if platform == "android":
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    PythonActivity = autoclass("org.kivy.android.PythonActivity")
    Intent = autoclass("android.content.Intent")
    String = autoclass("java.lang.String")

KV = """
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        height: .5

        MDTextField:
            id: dir_input
            hint_text: "Selected Directory"
            readonly: True
            multiline: False
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            size_hint_x: 0.9

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Choose Directory"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            size_hint: (0.9, None)
            height: "48dp"
            on_release: app.open_directory_picker()

        MDLabel:
            id: status_label
            text: ""
            halign: "center"
            valign: "top"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            height: .5

            Widget:

"""

class MinimalDirectoryChooser(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        if platform == "android":
            pass
            #request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def open_directory_picker(self):
        self.upd_notify("Opening directory picker...")
        intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
        chooser_title = String("Choose a directory")
        chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, chooser_title)
        PythonActivity.mActivity.startActivityForResult(chooser, 0)
        self.set_activity_result_listener(self.on_activity_result)

    @mainthread
    def set_activity_result_listener(self, func):
        PythonActivity.onActivityResultListener = func

    def on_activity_result(self, requestCode, resultCode, data):
        self.upd_notify("directory selected")
        if requestCode == 0 and resultCode == -1:  # RESULT_OK
            data_uri = data.getData()
            path = data_uri.getPath()
            self.root.ids.dir_input.text = path
            self.upd_notify(f"Directory: {path}")
        else:
            self.upd_notify("No directory selected.")

    def upd_notify(self, message):
        if self.root:
            self.root.ids.status_label.text = message

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MinimalDirectoryChooser().run()
```

After the user selects a directory with the Android file chooser, the app should display the file chosen via the upd_notify function